# Pronto doesn't post messages to GitHub

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm playing with [pronto](https://github.com/mmozuras/pronto) since done the line I wish to integrate it to my process.
I have followed the instruction on the Github page (at least I think so) but when I run pronto (with pronto-rubocop and pronto-spell) no messages are posted to Github even if I have several issues in the code.
You may check this [test repo](https://github.com/sigfrid/pronto-test).

In the repo I have

- a variable not in english
- a couple of not camel cased classes
- a misspelled commit message

Shouldn't pronto find this issues and post on Github?

After pushing my commit I execute pronto by running

> GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN=xxx482cb9b577de5a216xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx pronto
>   run -f github -c origin/master

The same happens when I run pronto locally `pronto run`: nothing is printed out.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-c/--commit` flag determines against which commit your current HEAD will be compared to. In your case, I don't see another branch besides `master`. You're probably running Pronto and comparing `master` against `origin/master`. That's very likely the same commit. You can observe it by:

`git show HEAD
git show master
git show origin/master`

To see some result in that repo, you can run Pronto like this (replaced `origin/master` with `HEAD~5`):

`GITHUB_ACCESS_TOKEN=xxx482cb9b577de5a216xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx pronto run -f github -c HEAD~5`

Or alternatively, create another branch, make some bad commits, `git push` and run Pronto while being on that branch.